# How to draw loop arrow and right left arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I attempt to draw my map and I'm stuck in drawing the following \

- drawing a loop above from 1 to 1
- drawing loop down from -1 to -1
- drawing bend above arrow from 2 and ending in 3 and bend down arrow from 3 and ending in 2
- drawing bend above arrow from -2 and ending in -3 and bend down arrow from -3 and ending in -2
- I also drew an "arrow" from 3 to -4 and another one from 4 to -3 but how to make them appear as a double-headed arrow connecting them. Sorry, I'm still a leTEX learner and I attempted a lot with no luck! This is my attempt and could you please help me and look at my handed drwawing picture as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz} % for a sample picture that is included below
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}

\tikzset{graph-1/.style = {
  line cap = round,
 line join = round,
         > = triangle 45,
 x=0.37cm, y=0.37cm,
 every node/.append style = {inner ysep=2mm}
                            }
        }% end of tikzset

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[graph-1]

\foreach \x in {0, 2, 4}
\foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle1, 2/\scriptstyle2, 4/\scriptstyle3, 6/\scriptstyle4, 8/\scriptstyle5}
\draw[fill=uuuuuu]  (\x,1.5) circle (1.3pt) node[above] {$\label$};
%
\foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle-1, 2/\scriptstyle -2, 4/\scriptstyle-3, 6/\scriptstyle-4, 8/\scriptstyle-5}
\draw[fill=uuuuuu]  (\x,-1.5) circle (1.3pt) node[below] {$\label$};
\foreach \x in {4}
\draw  (\x,1.5) -- (\x+2,-1.5);
\foreach \x in {6}
\draw  (\x,1.5) -- (\x-2,-1.5);
%
%\foreach \x in {0}  [it does not work to draw a loop]
%\draw [uuuuuu,->,gray, loop above] (\x) edge (\x)
%\draw [uuuuuu] (\x) --  (\x)
%\draw (\x) -- (\x)
%
\node[left] at (-.3,0) {$\pi=$};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why my laTEX commands didn't display properly in my question?

Comment: To format code blocks you need to indent them 4 spaces, or select them and use the `{}` symbol in the gui. Also, it's easier to help you if you post a *minimal* working example. In particular, please remove all unnecessary packages...

Comment: got it. Sure I will. thanks a lot Andrew and also thanks Habicht

Comment: May I ask you to clean your code up, i.e. to remove all the style files and macros that are not essential to the problem? BTW, the commended out `\draw` commands lack `;` in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution:

You should use the proper Tik*Z* commands if you want to create nodes with labels, that is: nodes with labels. Then you can easily draw arrows from one node to the other. Also, it does not make that much sense to use a `foreach` loop only for one single command.

I amended your code. The two `foreach` loops create the nodes and give them the names `t0`, `t2`, `t4`, `t6`, `t8` and `b0`, `b2` etc.

You may want to draw the arrows differently.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}

\tikzset{graph-1/.style = {
  > = triangle 45,
  x=0.37cm, y=0.37cm }
}% end of tikzset

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[graph-1]

    \foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle1, 2/\scriptstyle2, 4/\scriptstyle3, 6/\scriptstyle4, 8/\scriptstyle5}
      \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=above:{$\label$}] at (\x,1.5) (t\x) {};

    \foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle-1, 2/\scriptstyle -2, 4/\scriptstyle-3, 6/\scriptstyle-4, 8/\scriptstyle-5}
      \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=below:{$\label$}] at (\x,-1.5) (b\x) {};

    \draw[<->] (t6) -- (b8);
    \draw[<->] (t8) -- (b6);

    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (t0) to[loop below] (t0);
    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (b0) to[loop above] (b0);

    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (t2) to[bend right] (t4);
    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (t4) to[bend right] (t2);
    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (b2) to[bend left] (b4);
    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (b4) to[bend left] (b2);

    \node[left] at (-.3,0) {$\pi=$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \hfil

\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** With smaller arrow heads and the loops to the other side.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}

\tikzset{graph-1/.style = {
  >=stealth,
  x=0.37cm, y=0.37cm }
}% end of tikzset

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[graph-1]

    \foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle1, 2/\scriptstyle2, 4/\scriptstyle3, 6/\scriptstyle4, 8/\scriptstyle5}
      \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=above:{$\label$}] at (\x,1.5) (t\x) {};

    \foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle-1, 2/\scriptstyle -2, 4/\scriptstyle-3, 6/\scriptstyle-4, 8/\scriptstyle-5}
      \node[fill=uuuuuu,inner sep=1.3pt,circle,label=below:{$\label$}] at (\x,-1.5) (b\x) {};

    \draw[<->] (t6) -- (b8);
    \draw[<->] (t8) -- (b6);

    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (t0) to[out=135,in=45,looseness=30] (t0);
    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (b0) to[out=-135,in=-45,looseness=30] (b0);

    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (t4) to[bend left] (t2);
    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (t2) to[bend left] (t4);
    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (b2) to[bend left] (b4);
    \draw[uuuuuu,->] (b4) to[bend left] (b2);

    \node[left] at (-.3,0) {$\pi=$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \hfil

\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Habicht! You are kind and supportive. Yes, I wish if it's similar to the photo I uploaded

Comment: Hi Habicht, is there a way to make the head of an arrow small not big. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you so much Habicht! You are really helpful and I'm now so happy that this map was drawn

Answer (score 2):

slightly modified nice answer of [Jasper Habicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47927/jasper-habicht) (I could not resist to make it more concise :-( ):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}

\tikzset{graph-1/.style = {
  >={Stealth[length=1.5mm]},
  x=0.37cm, y=0.37cm,
  every label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize},
  dot/.style = {circle, fill=uuuuuu, inner sep=1.3pt}
  }
}% end of tikzset

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[graph-1]

    \foreach \x/\label in {0/1, 2/2, 4/3, 6/4, 8/5}
    {
      \node[dot,label=$\label$ ] at (\x, 1.5) (t\x) {};
      \node[dot,label=below:$-\label$] at (\x,-1.5) (b\x) {};
    }
    \node[left=3mm] at (0,0) {$\pi=$};

    \draw[uuuuuu,->]
        (t0) edge[out= 135,in= 45,looseness=30] (t0)
        (b0) edge[out=-135,in=-45,looseness=30] (b0)

        (t4) edge[bend left] (t2)
        (t2) edge[bend left] (t4)
        (b2) edge[bend left] (b4)
        (b4) edge[bend left] (b2);
    \draw[uuuuuu,<->]  (t6) edge (b8)
                (t8) edge (b6);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

the result is almost the same (tiny differences can be in arrows heads size):

[image]